# How to find out which application(s) are creating utun interfaces?

Tags: mac, network, vpn, ui

I see multiple utun interfaces from the `ifconfig` command output.
I know utun0 and utun1 are system interfaces. utun2 is the tunnel interface for my vpn client. But I can't find out which application is creating utun3-6 interfaces. I also don't see them in `netsts -rn` output.

Answer (score 4):

According to this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/113491) on the Apple developer forum, you should be able to get this information by running:

```
ifconfig -v utun3 | grep "agent domain"
```